# TYPO3 Manipulate Content Elements before rendering

Tags: typo3, rendering, hook, typo3-6.2.x

We added a new field into tt_contents and also, within TCA, to all content elements. Depending on the value within this field, we want to steer if the element should be rendered or not.

The behavior is similar to the content element access control for FE Users.

I'm searching for a Hook or an idea how to solve this. Unfortunately, I could not find anything helpful within felogin, also I tried the followings Hooks.

```
contentPostProc
render-preProcess
```

System Information:

- TYPO3: 6.2.19
- Flux: 7.2.3
- Fluidpages: 3.3.1

Would be absolutely awesome if someone could point me to a direction, thanks.

**Update**:
Had to change from a new field within the tt_contents table, to a mm relation table. This makes it more complex since the tables have to be joined.

**Update**:
Since there are several solutions, I tried a lot but ended with the `getRecordOverlay` hook. In the Interface `PageRepositoryGetRecordOverlayHookInterface`, which has to be used, you find a method for a pre- and a post-hook.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at the enableFields hook.

https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/084e22c249aef27755ddc88038daedcae81f1068/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Page/PageRepository.php#L1332

You can adapt the query that is used to get content element.

Comment: That sounded very promising but I could only find a `hook_checkEnableFields` hook which is for pages only and seems not triggered at all within my typo3 -.-

Comment: actually using `addEnableColumns` hook seems quite promising to me, unfortunately, this seems to not allow joins to different tables.

Comment: what are your thoughts about using `postUserFunc` or `stdWrap` Hook for this task?

Comment: Sure, joins won't work in the where clause part (which is what you can modify with this hook), but sub selects would work. But to say more, you need to be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 1):

With the old TYPO3 - I think you're using css_styled_content. You can simply add a new field (e.g. a checkbox) to tt_content with your own extension and some lines of TCA (I think you know how to insert this).
After this you could extend styles.content.get - something like
```

```
styles.content.get = CONTENT
styles.content.get {
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos=0 and yourfield=1
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
}
lib.yourcontent < styles.content.get
```

Comment: currently, I cannot imagine how I could implement this solution. I've seen the where is modified on left and right because of the colPos. If I would override the where with my check and also do a join for the mm table it would mess up the system, I guess.

Comment: after discussing this a bit in the typo3 slack I know how to deal with it but since I use vhs for rendering this will not work. What actually would work if I put my own view helper in, instead of using `<v:content.render column="0"/>`